# Test-case runner for Jenkins

Tags: groovy, automation

I am new to groovy/jenkins. I am using active choices parameter (projects) and active choices reactive parameter (testcases).

The code below will loop thru `$testcases` and execute shell scripts based on what is selected

```
//jenkins file

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Running test cases') {
            steps {
                script {
                echo 'running test cases'
                echo "you are abt to execute testcases - $testcases for project - $projects"
                String a = "$testcases"
                String[] str
                str = a.split(',')
                for( String values : str ){
                   // println(values)
                if("$projects" == 'project-1')
                    {
                     if("$values" == 'prj-1_tc-1')
                      {
                        echo "Executing the $values for $projects now"
                       }
                      if("$values" == 'prj-1_tc-2')
                      {
                        echo "Executing the $values for $projects .."
                       }
                }
                 
               if("$projects" == 'project-2')
                    {
                     if("$values" == 'prj-2_tc-1')
                      {
                        echo "Executing the $values for $projects now"
                       }
                      if("$values" == 'prj-2_tc-2')
                      {
                        echo "Executing the $values for $projects .."
                       }
                       if("$values" == 'prj-2_tc-3')
                      {
                        echo "Executing the $values for $projects .."
                       }
                    }
                   
             }
   
             }
           }
        }
    }
}
```